# count differences between words bash

Tags: bash, string-comparison

I'm trying to do a bash script to count differences between two words and delete those words with less than 2 different characters between them.

Example Input file:

```
hello
heggo
helloso
good
god
face
fake
rage
```

The output would be:

```
hello
heggo
helloso
rage
```

The input files are already formatted to be sorted alphabetticaly with lowercase letters and only one word per line.

The discarded words are:

Good -Only one letter difference from god , only an extra "O"

God - Same as good

Face - Only the C is different from other words.

Fake - Only the K is different from other words.

¿Any idea to handle this?

Comment: Did you write any code?

Comment: Are you comparing every word with every other word?

Comment: No, I don't have any clue to handle this

Comment: @123 yes, its my intention

Comment: Should good also be kept since has two oo? If your file has the word "erase" in it , should "erase" be kept or removed since has two ee (in different positions)?

Comment: @georgevasilou The goal of the code is to remove those words with less than two letter diferential. Erase would be kept since it has more than two different letters than any other word on the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work according to your description and comments.
Word "good" will also be kept since has two oo. 
Generally any word with two same letters in any position will be kept.

```
datasource=$(cat b.txt)
newdata=""
while IFS='' read -r line; do
found=0
readarray word < <(echo "$line" |fold -w1) #splits each line in a char array
    for eachletter in ${word[@]}; do
        found=$(echo "$line" | grep -o $eachletter |wc -w)
        if [[ $found -ge 2 ]] && [[ ${newdata[@]} != *"$line"* ]]; then 
            newdata+=( "$line" )
        fi
    done
unset word eachletter found
done <<< "$datasource"
echo -e "New Data \n" 
printf '%s\n' ${newdata[@]} # >newfile.txt
```